# jqGrid deleted row with confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, struts2

i am using struts2-jquery-jqgrid. i have buttons in the columns of the grid. i need to implement a confirm dialog when user clicks to delete.

SOLUTION:

// JAVASCRIPT THAT ADD BUTTONS IN THE COLUMN AND EVENT CLICK

```
$.subscribe('gridCompleteTopics2', function() {
var ids = jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
    var fila = jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid("getRowData", ids[i]);      
    link = "<button id='opener' onClick='deleteRecord(" + fila["idplanilla_det"]        + ");'>Open Dialog</button>";   
    jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{acti:link});  
}   
 });

function deleteRecord(id) {
alert(id);    
$("#dialogo").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "ACEPTAR": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "CANCELAR": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });    
   });

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
```

These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?

WORK.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not have multiple controls with the same ID. Here, you are creating `ids.length`-many buttons with id `opener`. Instead, assign a class to the buttons, e.g. `opener`.

Then, you should move your `.opener` `click` function after the buttons were created, as such:

```
$.subscribe("gridCompleteTopics2", function () {
    var ids = jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var fila = jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid("getRowData", ids[i]);
        link = "<button id='opener'>Open Dialog</button>";
        jQuery("#gridtable2").jqGrid("setRowData", ids[i], { acti: link });
    }

    $(".opener").on("click", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @user2765759, Make sure you put it within `$(function() { });`. And, what does `$.subscribe()` do?

Comment: $.subscribe() is a form of drive the handlers(events)